# Python PATH Issue Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, path, command-prompt

I keep getting the same issue with trying to pip install or run python -V. it comes up as **No Python at PATH**. I am on windows 10 operating system. The solution I keep coming to is going into the Environment Variables then changing system variables and user variables. However, it fails to work over every time and fails to change the path. 
I have tried looking up the problem for the past 2 days now and have not found a solution to my problem. I think I may have changed or deleted the original Path Variable. Unsure what I did but would love some help!!!

Comment: 1) You don't need to change system variables. Only need to change User variables.
2) You have to install Python somewhere (you haven't told us what kind of python and where have you installed python)
3) You have to add that path (where python is installed to your environment path.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed python first?

Go to this link: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Press on the Download Python button and once download, click on the .exe and follow the setup.

It should automatically add it to PATH but if it doesn't this link will help: https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/

Then restart Windows and python and pip should be installed.